# How to Disable Some Radio Buttons of Moschan's react-native-simple-radio-button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using Moschan's [react-native-simple-radio-button](https://github.com/moschan/react-native-simple-radio-button) and having difficulty to disabled some radio buttons. I have tried passing `disabled` item parameter with value `true` or `1` but no luck, it is still selectable.

**Source**:

```
radio_props = [
    { value: 1, label: 'one', disabled: true },
    { value: 2, label: 'two' },
    { value: 3, label: 'three', disabled: true },
];
```

**Component**:

```
import RadioForm from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';

...
<RadioForm
    radio_props={radio_props}
    initial={-1}
    buttonColor={'#169976'}
    selectedButtonColor={'#169976'}
    buttonSize={12}
    buttonOuterSize={25}
    onPress={(value) => { this.setState({ value:value }); }}
  />
...
```

Any idea how to solve this? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to address this issue by these steps:

- Open *node_modules/react-native-simple-radio-button/lib/SimpleRadioButton.js*
- Find `disabled={this.props.disabled}` around line 72, modify to: `disabled={this.props.disabled || obj.disabled ? obj.disabled : false}`
- Save and try again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass disabled props to RadioButtonLabel and RadioButtonInput. If it is disabled it won't call the onPress function. For example, you can do something like

```
<RadioButton>
  <RadioButtonInput
      {...otherRadioButtonInputProps}
      disabled={shouldDisable}
      buttonInnerColor={shouldDisable ? '#EEE' : '#000'}
      buttonOuterColor={shouldDisable ? '#EEE' : '#000'}
  />
  <RadioButtonLabel
      {...otherRadioButtonLabelProps}
      disabled={shouldDisable}
  />
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: This method works well, thank you. But now, selected radio button is missing inner dot, doesn't happen if we don't extract the RadioForm.